# Why can you not use binomials or similar strategies when ordering unique elements in unnumbered, non empty groups? Why stirling numbers?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I'm currently learning combinatorics and I'm trying to find what makes certain problems require stirling numbers. Consider the following problem: "How many ways can we arrange 10 sequentially numbered balls in unlabeled boxes so that none is empty?". I've seen problems that are similar but that can be solved by modelling them as an equation the likes of: X1 +X2 + X3 +...+Xn = 20. Is it specifically the uniqueness of the elements that dissalows us to model them like this?

Comment: Can a group be empty?

Comment: You can, in fact, use binomials in counting Stirling numbers of the second kind.  However, you have to correct for the fact that the boxes are unlabeled.

Answer (score 0):

"How many ways can we arrange 10 sequentially numbered balls in unlabeled boxes so that none is empty?". I've seen problems that are similar but that can be solved by modelling them as an equation the likes of: X1 +X2 + X3 +...+Xn = 20. Is it specifically the uniqueness of the elements that dissallows us to model them like this?

If the balls were unlabeled, and the boxes were labeled, then you could count the number of solutions to

$$x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_n = 10, \tag1 $$

where $x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 1}}.$

Obviously, you would have to have $n \leq 10.$  Here, $x_i$ refers to the number of **unlabeled** balls that go into **labeled** box-i.

There are two differences between the problem that you are trying to represent and the problem represented in (1) above:

- In your problem, the balls are sequentially numbered (i.e. labeled).  In the problem represented in (1) above, the balls are unlabeled.
- In your problem, the boxes are unlabeled.  In the problem represented in (1) above, the boxes are labeled. 
  For example, with $n=4$, the Math problem represented by (1) above would consider the two solutions of $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) = (4,3,2,1)$ and $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) = (1,2,3,4)$ as distinct.

One attempt at adjustment is that since the balls are labeled, you multiply the number of solutions to (1) above by $(10)!$.  This is **wrong**.

For example, consider the solution $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) = (4,3,2,1).$

A reasonable question to ask is : how can you adjust the enumeration in (1) above to accommodate the altered premises.

You could reason that instead of multiplying by $(10)!$, you should multipy by

$$\binom{10}{4} \times \binom{6}{3} \times \binom{3}{2} \times \binom{2}{1}. \tag2 $$

Ignoring the separate problem that the boxes must be considered unlabeled, you encounter the problem that the solution $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) = (3,3,2,2)$ would require the **different** scaling factor of

$$\binom{10}{3} \times \binom{7}{3} \times \binom{4}{2} \times \binom{2}{2}. $$

Note that I am assuming that if (for example) the first box contains ball-1, ball-2, ball-3, it is irrelevant which of the three balls was the first one placed in the first box.

So, ignoring the fact that the boxes are unlabeled, different solutions to (1) above would have to be **scaled differently**.

The separate issue, is how to scale to adjust that the boxes are unlabeled.

The solution $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) = (4,3,2,1)$ would have to be scaled by $\dfrac{1}{4!}$, while the solution $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) = (3,3,2,2)$ would have to be scaled by $\dfrac{1}{\binom{4}{2}}$.

So, the **second** scaling factor must also be altered, depending on the solution.  The whole point of Stirling numbers was to recognize problems that (ordinarily) would have no easy enumeration.  So, Stirling numbers evolved to provide **syntactic sugar** to represent the enumeration of such problems.

As a similar example, consider trying to express (for example) $\sqrt{2}$ as the limit of an infinite series of rational numbers.  The symbol $\sqrt{2}$ evolved to provide the corresponding **syntactic sugar**.